# redirect with params fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make redirect:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'forex', :action => 'index', :format => :csv, :paramer =>      instrument_for_sql
```

but in log I have:

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/forex/index.csv?paramer=AUDJPY
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 150ms

But if I paste http://localhost:3000/forex/index.csv?paramer=AUDJPY directly it works.

Any ideas?

```
class ForexController < ApplicationController
def index
instrument_for_sql = params[:paramer]
receive_csv
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv 
end 
end

routes.rb
match '/forex', :controller => 'forex', :action => 'index', :format => 'csv'
```

Comment: check 'paramer', it with mistake, maybe it cause the problem

Comment: Show us your `ForexController#index` action please.

Comment: Add client request headers, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I tried to make redirect in respond_to block. Outside it works. When I use format.html in respond_to it works too.

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'forex', :action => 'index', :format => :csv, :paramer => instrument_for_sql }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  instrument_for_sql = params[:paramer]
  receive_csv
  redirect_to :controller => 'forex', :action => 'index', :format => :csv, :paramer =>      instrument_for_sql
end
```

Try this, remove respond_to block.

Comment: In question the index controller do not redirected to itself. Its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Rails sets the responce format for you in the case of generated url, and returns the [406 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) because client do not accept such a responce. So try the alternatives:

- redirect_to url_for(:only_path => true, :controller => 'forex',
  :action => 'index', :format => :csv, :paramer => instrument_for_sql)
- redirect_to url_for( :controller => 'forex', :action => 'index', :format => :csv, :paramer => instrument_for_sql), :status => 301